# How to solve".kv is loaded multiples times "error in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a realy simple program in Kivy with 3 windows.But when I run it it says

```
The file C:\Users\ab79\Documents\GPX WEATHER\weather.kv is loaded multiples times, you might have unwanted behaviors.
```

I can run it but there is actually an unwanted behaviour, one of my three windows desappears !
When I run the code now it is skipping the "infoWindow" in the middle. I can observe it since I put FloatLayout instead of GridLayout, but the error message was already here before. I don't understand what's going wrong.

Here is the minimal code

python

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()

class ImportFileWindow(Screen):
    pass

class InfoWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ResultWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("weather.kv")

class WeatherApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__=="__main__":
    WeatherApp().run()
```

Kivy

````
WindowManager:
    ImportFileWindow:
    InfoWindow:
    ResultWindow:



<Label>    
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size    
    font_size:40
    color:  0,0,0,1

<Button>
    font_size:40
    color:  0,0,0,1
    background_normal: ''

<ImportFileWindow>:
    name: "import"


    Button:
        text: "Importer"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "info"
            root.manager.transition.direction="left"


<InfoWindow>:
    name: "info"
    day: day


    FloatLayout:
        cols:2
        size:root.width,root.height/2


        Label:
            text:"Jour :"

        TextInput:
            id:day
            multiline:False

    Button:
        text:"Valider"
        on_release:
            app.root.current="result"
            root.manager.transition.direction="left"
    Button:
        text:"Retour"
        on_release:
            app.root.current="import"
            root.manager.transition.direction="right"


<ResultWindow>:
    name: "result"

    Button:
        text: "Retour"
        on_release:
            app.root.current="info"
            root.manager.transition.direction="right"



       ```

The error is are since the begining but the real issues are here since I use a FloatLayout instead of GridLayout.
Any ideas ?

:)
````

Comment: Do not delete the [mre] or add SOLVED to the title of your question. Read [ask], [answer] and review the [tour]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `weather.kv` is loaded automatically, see [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv). But you are also loading it explicitly with:

```
kv = Builder.load_file("weather.kv")
```

I think you just need to delete the above line, and change your `WeatherApp` class to:

```
class WeatherApp(App):
    pass
```

Comment: I did it and the error message desappears which is a good point  but nothing goes in the GUI and the result screen is black :(

Comment: If you use the automatic load, then your `App` should not have a `build()` method.

Comment: You just solved my problem ! I couldn't delete the buidler.load_file line so I changed the name of the kv file to break the automatic load and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign full code of your 'kv' file in to a variable(ex:- kv = """kv code here"""). And create a new function to load it using `Builder.load_string(kv)`. After that use 'kivy.clock' module to schedule that function once when the build method is started.